# Evolution of the temperature of electron proton gas in universe after recombination

Tags: cosmology, universe

How can I mathematically find the evolution of temperature of matter in universe over time?
Suppose I start with a mixture of free electrons and protons. After sometime, they will cool down, and a part of them form hydrogen during recombination, and other part will remain as free electrons. After that, they will decouple after a point of time.

Over the whole time scale, how can I arrive at the equations describing the evolution of temperature of the free electron proton gas, and hydrogen atoms?

Comment: Your description seems like you are intentionally ignoring the temperature of some of the mass due to the thermonuclear energy produced in stars.  Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. I am not bothered with the stellar temperature. I am working on early universe.

Comment: I now guess, you are interested in a period of time preceding recombination as well as a bit after recombination. Some time prior to recombination you may assume a plasma. I would suggest to keep your first attempt as simple as possible you assume the plasma consists entirely of protons and electrons. During recombination, some electrons get bound to protons making the stuff a combination of plasma and hydrogen atoms. At the end of recombination, it becomes all hydrogen atoms. I recommend  you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_(cosmology) as well as its references.